Q: how to best connect a rigid duct to a heating duct boot register without its round neck?
We have the original 2.25x10(rectangle)x4(round) inch and 2.25x12x6 inch heating duct register boots remaining in our 1960 house, after the ducts with asbestos insulation have been removed.
But these register boots remaining do NOT have "round neck" left on them, into which the crimped side of rigid ducts can be slotted in.
Q: what is the best way to connect a rigid duct in this case, without replacing all the register boots ?

So yours end in just sharp sheet metal ?  You can snip the metal and make 90 flanges.  You can insert two flanges into a hole you cut into your trunk and leave two out.  You can use sheet metal screws to fasten the flanges that you've cut and bent into your trunk line.  You'd then metal tape or use duct sealing compound.  I like red devil 0841DX F Seal 181.
